# install and using hipi to analyse about it

Tags: hadoop

I don't know how to install and analyse hipi. I have tried to add jar files and added the source code given in downlods of the given link.
http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Well it is pretty much simple.Here are the steps

1)Install Hadoop-2.6.0(recommended).You can follow from [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php)

2)Install HIPI and build using gradle. You can follow from [here](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/gettingstarted.html)